# How to write a code that draws a certain object, in this case a rectangle, where the coordinates are specified with mouse clicks?

Tags: java, graphics

How do I code an applet that is supposed to draw a rectangle after every second click event of the MouseListener, where the coordinates are specified by the places clicked, x for the first click, and y for the second?

Comment: start with a simple code to post so others can help you in improving it. just posting problem does not show much effort from your side. something like getxyOnFirstClick(), getxyOnSecondClick(). then calculate other two points based on these. then you can use some library to draw lines and make rectangle.

Comment: I suggest using [Processing](https://processing.org/) for graphics, if you want to stick to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following, where it will draw a rectangle from the first point to the second point.

```
boolean first = true;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    int x, y, width, height;

    if (first) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        first = false;
     } if (!first) {
        width = Math.abs(e.getX() - x);
        height = Math.abs(e.getY() - y);
        first = true;
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: For some reason it keeps drawing it on the first click.. as a dot, trying to solve it myself, the math seems to be correct but something is either missing or present that is causing a problem..

Comment: Can you post your entire code for me to test?  Also, check out the related questions on the side for more help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Full code.

```
public class PravougaonikApp extends Applet implements MouseListener{
public PravougaonikApp() {
    addMouseListener(this);

    setSize(300,300);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

boolean first = true;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    int x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0;


        if (first) {
        x = e.getX();

     } if (!first) {

        y = e.getY();
        width = Math.abs(e.getX() - x);
        height = Math.abs(e.getY() + y);
        first = true;
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
     }
     first = false;

}


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking of something in the lines of this:
public PravougaonikApp() {
        addMouseListener(this);

```
    setSize(300,300);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
int i=0;
int x,y;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    if(i%2==0) {
    x=e.getX();
    i++;
    }
    if(i%2==1) {
    y=e.getY();
    i--;
    g.drawRect(x, y, 100, 50);
    }

}
```

It keeps drawing rectangles at the first click, and yes, I know I specified the values of width and height by 100 and 50, but that is only due to the functions demand... My question is how to write it in a fashion where those parameters are not required, or at least, where the parameters of width and height are specified by the coordinates.

Comment: Please edit you question above with these new details.